# Web scraping on a dropdown list in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am new doing web scraping, and I want to know what is the error in the following code when I want to do web scraping in R from this web site : https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/ebti/ebti_consultation.jsp?Lang=en where the first step is: 1. select from the second country, Austria , onwards,  from a dropdown option in front of "Issuing country " , then I have more steps, but I want at least the list of the countries in this first option. thanks in advance

```
library(rvest)
library(pdftools)
library(RCurl)
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

# Define the URL of the website for Austria
#url <- "https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/ebti/ebti_consultation.jsp?Lang=en&Lang=en&refcountry=AT&reference=&valstartdate1=01-01-2022&valstartdate=01%2F01%2F2022&valstartdateto1=&valstartdateto=&valenddate1=&valenddate=&valenddateto1=&valenddateto=&suppldate1=&suppldate=&nomenc=&nomencto=&keywordsearch1=&keywordsearch=&specialkeyword=&keywordmatchrule=OR&excludekeywordsearch1=&excludekeywordsearch=&excludespecialkeyword=&descript=&orderby=0&Expand=true&offset=1&viewVal=&isVisitedRef=true&allRecords=0&showProgressBar=true"


# Send a GET request to the website and get the content
#response <- getURL(url)
#page <- read_html(response)

# Define the URL of the website
url <- "https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/ebti/ebti_consultation.jsp?Lang=en"

# Send a GET request to the website and get the content
response <- getURL(url)
page <- read_html(response)

# Step 1: Select from the second country onwards in the list of "Issuing country"

dropdown_options <- page %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//select[@id='refcountry']/option[position() > 1]") %>%
  html_text()
```

Comment: It's a javascript-driven page,  content available for rvest is quite different compared to what you see in your broswer's dev tools or in Selector Gadget(unless you disable javascript for that site in your browser). List items you are looking for are fetched  from https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/ebti/country_combo/country_combo_en.js .  Why do you (think you) need to interact with the form? All search parameters seem to be included in results page URL.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Actually, I posted only the first step, the steps are: 1. select from the second country, AT , onwards, in the list of Issuing country, after that 2.select in "Start date of validity" the date 01/01/2022. 3.click on "Star search" 4.once this site is open, I mean the site of that specific first country at that date, then click on the first link on the list of "BTI Reference" 5. once is opened that link, then save that as a PDF. 6. also save that as a excel table where the variables or columns are : BTI Reference, Issuing country,  Start date of validity,…, Keywords.

Comment: What I'm trying to say here is that rvest is not able to extract country list from the page source as it's not included there, your browser builds the list it by executing javascript, but rvest can't do that.  And you can just build the search URL without dealing with the form as all parameters you'd set through the form are included there (`selected country : `AT` ; selected start date of validity: `01-01-2020`): 
`https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/ebti/ebti_consultation.jsp?Lang=en&Lang=en&refcountry=AT&reference=&valstartdate1=01-01-2020& ... `

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I will check it and I will come back if I have another question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that can be considered :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
url <- "https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/ebti/ebti_consultation.jsp?Lang=en"
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(5)
doc <- IEApp$document()
web_Obj_Dropdown <- doc$getElementByID("refcountry")
strsplit(web_Obj_Dropdown$innerHtml(), "</option>")

[[1]]
 [1] "<option id=\"option_template\" value=\"\">-----" "<option value=\"AT\">Austria"                   
 [3] "<option value=\"BE\">Belgium"                    "<option value=\"BG\">Bulgaria"                  
 [5] "<option value=\"HR\">Croatia"                    "<option value=\"CY\">Cyprus"                    
 [7] "<option value=\"CZ\">Czech rep."                 "<option value=\"DK\">Denmark"                   
 [9] "<option value=\"EE\">Estonia"                    "<option value=\"FI\">Finland"                   
[11] "<option value=\"FR\">France"                     "<option value=\"DE\">Germany"                   
[13] "<option value=\"GR\">Greece"                     "<option value=\"HU\">Hungary"                   
[15] "<option value=\"IE\">Ireland"                    "<option value=\"IT\">Italy"                     
[17] "<option value=\"LV\">Latvia"                     "<option value=\"LT\">Lithuania"                 
[19] "<option value=\"LU\">Luxembourg"                 "<option value=\"MT\">Malta"                     
[21] "<option value=\"NL\">Netherlands"                "<option value=\"PL\">Poland"                    
[23] "<option value=\"PT\">Portugal"                   "<option value=\"RO\">Romania"                   
[25] "<option value=\"SK\">Slovakia"                   "<option value=\"SI\">Slovenia"                  
[27] "<option value=\"ES\">Spain (excluding XC XL)"    "<option value=\"SE\">Sweden"                    
[29] "<option value=\"XI\">UK (Northern Ireland)"      "<option value=\"GB\">United Kingdom"
```